# luigi-Failed building wheel while pip install luigi

Tags: python, pip, luigi

```
error: can't copy 'luigi\static\visualiser\lib\URI.js': doesn't exist or not a regular file

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for luigi
Running setup.py clean for luigi
Failed to build luigi
Installing collected packages: luigi
Running setup.py install for luigi ... error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be [an issue](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/2017) with the latest package (version 2.6.0) on some operating systems and python version. Issue is closed but users are still reporting the installation is broken in some cases.

It works if you install version 2.5.0:

```
pip install luigi==2.5.0
```

Comment: Helpful workaround. 2.6.0 doesn't seem to be working on CentOS 7 using virtualenv